# Why can't Fourier Transforms be used to extend data sets?

Tags: fourier-transform

I have been trying to have some python code take some wave created by adding sine waves together, which has some number of samples and computing a discrete Fourier transform to get the frequencies of these sine waves. I then want to use these frequencies to make a wave that consists of the same frequencies of the original wave but extended by some amount. I can't seem to find a way to do this, so is it a limitation of the library I'm using or is there some mathematical reason I can't do this? My primary knowledge with regard to Fourier transforms is to do with continuous Fourier transforms and I can't see any reason why you couldn't do what I am trying to do with these.

Comment: To use the DFT you are assuming you apply the transform on exactly one period of a periodic function. Then, if you transform back you get the original period. To extend, no need to transform back and forth: just copy the data as necessary to get another period, or more. It's probably not the answer you are expecting, but the DFT is doing nothing more here.

Comment: Of course it's different if you want to transform to frequency domain, filter out some frequencies you don't want, and extend you data with filtered data. But then the DFT has nothing to do with the extension, it's only used for the filter.

Comment: Thanks for all the help